# Tuning skopt to minimise correctly

Tags: optimization, scipy, bayesian-optimization

I have a problem where I need to fit a pair of parameters in a model to best fit observed data for hundreds of instances. I need to determine these parameters to high accuracy, rather than just finding a "reasonable optimum". Because of the cost of running the model (~1 to 20s), and the number of instances to fit, and the fact that my error function must be evaluated numerically (so no analytic derivative function) I was looking at Bayesian optimization as a suitable approach. My work is in Python, so I've been using the `skopt` package.

Although the parameters can vary significantly from one instance to the next, the general shape of the error surface (error as a function of mismatch of parameters) looks quite consistent. I have evaluated this systematically for one instance below:

[image: Gross scale error surface]

There is some noise in this surface that introduces local minima, but there is clearly one global minimum. The surface is quite strongly peaked close to this minimum, as can be seen at higher resolution:

[image: Fine scale error surface around global mimumum]

In the first image you can see the points sampled when I run `gp_minimize` on the error function using the default settings

```
from skopt import gp_minimize
params_init = res = gp_minimize(model_err, [(-10.,10.),(-10.,10.)])
```

I was surprised that there was little convergence towards the minimum, and I would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve this. I have already tried increasing the number of random samples to initiate the optimizer, and initiating with a 5 by 5 uniform grid of samples (I can't sample much finer without making the optimization process prohibitively long). Is there some way to make use of my knowledge of the general shape of the error surface within the optimizer? Or is my problem poorly suited to a GP-based approach?

Comment: It might help to increase the noise level: `gp_minimize(model_err, [(-10.,10.),(-10.,10.)], noise=1.0)` or higher.

Comment: @JLT thanks for the suggestion. I was also thinking a different kernel might be required to cope with the sharp peak. I've moved on from this problem but may revisit again if time allows.